# Convert json to excel and upload that to s3 using node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I created a JSON by querying dB and from that JSON I created an excel using the following code

```
const json2xls = require('json2xls');
const xls = json2xls(option);
```

where 'option' is the JSON.
Now I uploaded the excel file to S3 bucket, but when I'm opening that file. I'm getting error telling we found some error with the content in excel. can anyone help me with this
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be due to a corrupt Xls file. Your file might be created properly.

You can try this

```
var json2xls = require('json2xls');
var fs =require("fs")
var jsonArr = [{
    foo: 'bar',
    qux: 'moo',
    poo: 123,
    stux: new Date()
},
{
    foo: 'bar',
    qux: 'moo',
    poo: 345,
    stux: new Date()
}];

var xls = json2xls(jsonArr);

fs.writeFileSync('data.xlsx', xls, 'binary');
```

Comment: Thanks Aditya for the response i tried this but still im getting that error

Comment: 'We found a problem with some content in test.xlsx.Do you want to try as much as we can'.  When I'm clicking yes for this it is showing next error 'Excel cannot open this file because this file format is not valid'

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted

Comment: This is great for when you're trying to save the file onto your file system but the question is about uploading to AWS.

Comment: The issue was with the Xls file. The file was not in the proper format and that's why it was giving an error while opening in S3. Please go through the question once again.